# javax.servlet.HttpServletRequest.getContentLength() right behavior in EE6?

Tags: java, servlets

My question duplicates [javax.servlet.HttpServletRequest.getContentLength() returns int only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423285/javax-servlet-httpservletrequest-getcontentlength-returns-int-only), however I am interested in different. What is proper return of 
javax.servlet.HttpServletRequest.getContentLength() when content length is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE?
The question author assumes it is -1. However servlet specification doesn't cover the topic. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getContentLength%28%29
It says as -1 when length is unknown. It is incorrect because length is known, simply can't fit Integer.
EE7 covers the gap
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getContentLength%28%29
and even introduces getContentLengthLong().
However my question is if I implement EE6 specification what is right behavior in case of content length > Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the JavaDoc for the [Java EE 7 version of ServletRequest.getContentLength()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getContentLength%28%29).

It says quite clearly:

> ... or -1 if the length is not known or is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE

Beware that if you're attempting to read a large request body it will almost certainly be chunked anyway. Many HTTP firewalls and proxies will chunk large bodies as a matter of course.

Comment: You're quite right - I must have been overdoing the multitasking that day. I will remove this answer shortly and provide a better one.